# Brother MFC 7360 scanner - Scans from ADF are legal size, even though paper isn't

Tags: scanner

I've got a Brother MFC 7360 setup with network scanning. I redid the network scanning a while back to run on Linux.

In all cases, scanning works fine, however, when I scan using the ADF, all of the scans show up as legal-sized (8.5x14), even though the page being scanned is letter size (8.5x11).

If I scan by placing the page on the glass, it scans properly as letter size.

Note that I have intercepted the raw scanned image that the scanner is returning - it's definitely sending an 8.5x14 image.

I've run through every setting I can see on the machine, and the only thing that has to do with scan size is the setting for the glass, and it's set to letter.

I did try blowing out the ADF with canned air, but that has no effect. I can't see any scraps stuck anywhere (though I've not completely disassembled the ADF).

Anyone have any good ideas on what's going on here? It almost seems like the ADF isn't properly registering end of page or something?

Answer (score 0):

I've 'solved' the issue by changing the scanning scripts to force the page to letter size. I suspect that for some reason the ADF actually doesn't know how big the page is.